# Seem to lose the user_id when linking to same Facebook app

Tags: php, facebook, graph

I have this test App as an iFrame in Facebook:

```
<?
require_once('src/facebook.php');

$config = array(
  'appId' => '123',
  'secret' => '123456',
  'fileUpload' => true,
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
echo "[" . $user_id . "]<br>";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head></head>
  <body>
  <br>
  <form action="" method="post"><input name="input" type="submit" value="Submit test"></form><br> 
  <a href="?hallo=1">Link test</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I use FaceBook PHP SDK version 3.1.1-25

What I see in IE 9:
I vistit this app and it displays my user ID between brackets. 
But when I press the submit button or when I click on the link I re-enter the app and the user-id is 0.

Only in Chrome it seems to work fine, there it keeps displaying my user id like I would expect it to do.

What am I doing wrong, or else, how can i make a multi page app and use the user-id on the next page?

Comment: not sure if it's related to the P3P header, read more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/)

Answer (score 0):

One Way is you can store user in `SESSION`.
Other way you can declare object of `FACEBOOK` class as global in the page you want to use facebook object and you can call "`$facebook->getUser()`".

```
global $facebook;
$user = $facebook->getUser();
echo $user;
```

Comment: The Facebook php-sdk [already saves](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php#L51) the user id in the session.